# How to recalculate/reinitialize variables of a class in python

Tags: python, class

I have some `app.py` in which I do the following:

```
Trader = Trader(settings)
while True:
    try:
        Trader.analyse_buys()
```

Now I have the following in `trader.py`

```
def __init__(self):
    self.since = self.calculate_since()
    ...

def analyse_buys():
   dosomething()
```

So the `analyse_buys()` will run in a loop without a new calculation of the value `since`.

What could be a possible solution to recalculate my variables in the `__init__` function again before starting the function again?

Comment: Run `__init__` again, pretty much by instantiating a new `Trader()`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to still save some state in `Trader`, i.e. instantiating a new one with

```
trader = Trader()
```

isn't an option, consider moving the bits that need to be reinitialized into another function, and calling that both within `__init__()` and from elsewhere:

```
class Trader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state_that_shouldnt_be_re_prepared = ...
        self.prepare()  # (or whatever is a sensible name)

    def prepare(self):
        # do things


# ...

trader = Trader()
while ...:
    if something:
        trader.prepare()
```